# Convert byte array to .wav file

Tags: ios, c, audio

```
NSUInteger len = [response length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte *)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [response bytes], len);

    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:len];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self documentDirectory], OWAudioDoorKeyFileName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:soundFilePath
                                                   error:nil];
    }

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:soundFilePath
                                            contents:soundData
                                          attributes:nil];
```

This is my code but that file cannot play
Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file getting created in the document directory in wav format? If yes then there seems to be a problem by the way in which you are converting the byte data into NSData

Comment: @NSDumb yes, the file has been created but It can't play. I think It has some problem when convert byte to NSData. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Try validating the response from the server side just to be sure, you may be getting an invalid byte array from the server. If not then its the conversion that you are doing in the Objective C end. You need to ask the developer who has created the service to validate the response at server side for you.

Comment: @NSDumb I can't do that because It's 3rd party API and I'm sure that data is correct because Android Implementing has no problem.